# How to increase performance of Ajax Extentions in ASP.NET and stop website from going down?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, performance, hosting

I am running a discussion website where people come and discuss on a topic and also vote on it. The voting system is ajax based where clicking on up button increases the vote and down decreases the vote as in stackoverflow.com. The website is highly engaging.

What is the problem coming is that, after 5 or 6 votes or comments in a row the website goes down. Means whenever I vote 4 or 5 comments rapidly than website goes down. I asked my hosting provider, they said that I should buy a VPS or dedicated hosting to remove this fault. But I want to confirm from you people that can this problem be solved using shared hosting? As we have a very less budget so can't afford high priced hosting plans. So please tell any programming solution available. And also tell me that the solution provided by my hosting provider is correct or not?

Example vote up code:

```
protected void button1_Click(...)
{
    new DatabaseOps.incrementUp(topicID.text); //topic id is a label
    button1.Enabled=false;
}
```

The button is enclosed in a update panel that update automatically.

Comment: Could you please give an example of the code you are using for one of those buttons?

Comment: I edited my question and cannot provide much code than this.

Comment: Do you use an update panel? Are you using .NET 4.0 with integrated app pool?

Comment: what does `DatabaseOps.incrementUp(...);` look like? Can you post that code as well?

Comment: actually @BrianDriscoll this function executes simple update query and I am telling that my code is working but the website goes down after regular calling of this function.

Comment: If your website is crashing after calling this code several times then I'd venture to guess it's not really working as you expect.

Comment: actually the code is working. The up voting system is incrementing the vote but website crashed after 5 or 7 votes in a row. if you like to experience it yourself than you can have a visit to my website http://www.wrangle.in , don't think its an advertisement. I just wanted you to experience the error that I may be unable to tell here. Just visit once and you will find the error when voting some comments rapidly in a row.

Comment: @ShivaPareek Maybe I should be more explicit: I agree that your increment code may be incrementing correctly, but I think there also may be a side effect in that code that is causing your website to crash. For instance, if you are not properly disposing of your database connections...

Answer (score 0):

There must be a critical error coming on your website. By default in IIS, application pool takes down website after 5 critical errors come in a row. I do not think getting a dedicated hosting would resolve your problem until you fix your code.

Comment: Windows is bad at it. It never helped me in that over the years. All what gets recorded, can be viewed through Administrative Tools > Events Viewer. But I think Shared Hosting does not provide access to Event Viewer entries. I personally think if something is not handled in code, it will not otherwise be easy to catch in Windows Server environment

Having said that, Event Viewer itself does not give too much of explanation. Enclose all of your code with TRY/CATCH blocks throughout the application, and log errors to text file.